# How would I print numbers from a vector onto a file?

Tags: c++, file-io

//Here is my code thus far

//HERE I SIMPLY TAKE IN A FILE FULL OF NUMBERS, INCLUDING DECIMAL NUMBERS

```
ifstream infile;
infile.open("Numbers.txt");
if (!infile) {
    cout << "Unable to open the file" << endl;
    return;
}
```

//CREATING VECTORS TO STORE THOSE NUMBERS IN

```
vector<int> iNumbers;
vector<double> dNumbers;

    if (infile) {
        int i;
        double d;

    while (infile >> i && infile >> d) {
        iNumbers.push_back(i);
        dNumbers.push_back(d);
    }

    infile.close();
}
```

/*
NOW ATTEMPTING TO PRINT OR PLACE THOSE NUMBERS INTO TWO DIFFERENT FILES PUTTING THE INTEGERS IN integer.txt AND PUTTING THE DOUBLES IN doubles.txt
*/

```
ofstream integerOut("integer.txt");

vector<int>::iterator ii;
for (ii = iNumbers.begin(); ii != iNumbers.end(); ++ii)
{
    if (ii = int {

    }
    integerOut << *ii << endl;
    cout << *ii << endl;
}

integerOut.close();

ofstream doubleOut("double.txt");

vector<double>::iterator dd;
for (dd = dNumbers.begin(); dd != dNumbers.end(); ++dd)
{
    doubleOut << *dd << endl;
    cout << *dd << endl;
}

doubleOut.close();


}
```

//MY CODE ONLY GIVES ME THE FIRST TWO NUMBERS FOR MY integer.txt FILE AND THE LAST DECIMALS FOR MY double.txt.  WHAT AM I DOING WRONG?

Further explanation:
I have a file named Numbers.txt with numbers containing

1

5

9.4

3

4

6.3

5

2.2

I am taking the integers and trying to place them into the interger.txt file and I am taking the doubles and placing them into the double.txt file.  But in my code I am receiving for integers

1

2

9

3

4

6

5

2

when I want to receive

1

5

3

4

5

only

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: @herohuyongtao my code only gives me the first two numbers for my integer.txt file and the last decimals for my double.txt file.  I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong so I could simply take in and print out integers to integer vector then output it into integer.txt and do the same for double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard algorithm `std::copy`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

//...

std::ofstream integerOut( "integer.txt" );

if ( integerOut ) 
{
   std::copy( iNumbers.begin(), iNumbers.end(), 
              std::ostream_iterator<int>( integerOut, " " ) );
}  


std::ofstream doubleOut( "double.txt" );

if ( doubleOut ) 
{
   std::copy( dNumbers.begin(), dNumbers.end(), 
              std::ostream_iterator<double>( doubleOut, " " ) );
}
```

Or you can write a code where you will control the output yourself. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

//...

std::ofstream integerOut( "integer.txt" );

for ( int x : iNumbers )
{
    if ( !( integerOut << x << ' ' ) ) break;
}


std::ofstream doubleOut( "double.txt" );

for ( double x : dNumbers )
{
    if ( !( doubleOut << x << ' ' ) ) break;
}
```

As for the input then as I have understood two integers are followed by one double in the file. So you need to read numbers accordingly.

```
int i1, i2;
double d;

bool valid = true;
while ( valid ) 
{
   if ( valid = infile >> i1 ) iNumbers.push_back( i1 );
   if ( valid && ( valid = infile >> i2 ) ) iNumbers.push_back( i2 );
   if ( valid && ( valid = infile >> d ) ) dNumbers.push_back( d );
}
```

If you do not know whether the next number in the file is integer or double you can distiguish them by the presence of the period in the number. For example

```
std::string value;

while ( infile >> value )
{
   if ( value.find( '.' ) != std::string::npos )
   {
      double d = std::stod( value );
      dNumbers.push_back( d );
   }
   else
   {
      int i = std::stoi( value );
      iNumbers.push_back( i );
   }
}
```

Comment: Further explanation:
I have a file named Numbers.txt with numbers containing

1

5

9.4 

3 

4 

6.3 

5 

2.2 

I am taking the integers and trying to place them into the interger.txt file and I am taking the doubles and placing them into the double.txt file.  But in my code I am receiving for integers 

1 

2 

9 

3 

4 

6 

5 

2 

when I want to receive

1 

5 

3 

4 

5 

only

Comment: Lets just say the integers and doubles within the Numbers.txt file are at random and have no pattern of any kind, how would I go about taking in only the integers into a vector and only doubles into a separate vector to then print the the integers from the integers vector into the integers.txt file and same for the doubles?

Comment: @anonymous I have uodated my post.

Comment: You helped me a lot with this question, I was wondering if you could also help me with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177460/what-would-be-the-best-way-to-implement-recursion?noredirect=1#comment35447125_23177460

Comment: @anonymous Your question is put on hold. I can not answer.